# How to update same fields but different tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, macros

Good Day!

First of all I am new to making database so I am really hoping the pros out there could enlighten me. I am currently working on a student grading database. Each student has 10 subjects (math, science, etc). Each subject has 4 grading periods.Now this is the case.

I am using `MS Access 2013`

Let's just take one subject: Mathematics. I have 5 tables:

```
 1. student_profile
 2. math_1st_grading
 3. math_2nd_grading
 4. math_3rd_grading
 5. math_4th_grading
```

Each of the tables above contain a field: Student Name.

I have a form for the student_profile table. What i want to do is when i enter data into the Student Name using the form, the Student Name fields for all the math grading tables will be updated.

I was thinking of making an update query for each of the math tables and run them simultaneously using a macro. But I don't know how to do that. It's just an idea for me.

Ive also read ideas like making an "after update" even in the form but i don't know much about macros and expression builders.

Please help me with this.  Maybe i do not really know much about normalizing my tables  please give some solutions for this.

Your response is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: u dont need to give student name for all the table .except student profile . give other table the student foreign reference.this would be easy

Comment: The solution is to normalize your tables.  If you don't know much about that, learn.  I just went to my copy of MS-Access and pressed the F1 key.  Under Getting Started was a link to database design basics.  Your welcome.

Comment: what is the use of   2. math_1st_grading
 3. math_2nd_grading
 4. math_3rd_grading
 5. math_4th_grading tables. can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad database design. Look at what entities you are talking about: students, subjects and grading periods. So it is very likely you need exactly these tables.

- **student** (student_id, *firstname, lastname, entrydate, ...*)
- **subject** (subject_id, *name*)
- **grading** (grading_id, *name*)

Then you combine these in a table to get to each student's subjects and gradings:

- **student_subject** (student_id, subject_id, grading_id, *result*)

So when a student's name changes you only have to update one record in your database. When a subject gets added, simply insert one more record into your subject table. And so on.

This is however just an example. With this design you would be able to let students have different subjects for instance. If this is not desired, another model might be better. But it should give you the idea. First think of the entities you are dealing with, then think about how they are related.